# json записывает null bd

Tags: php, json

```
function js($path,$mon){
    file_put_contents($path, json_encode($mon));
}

        if((int)$user_id > 0){
        if(file_exists('players/money/'.$user_id)){
            $usermon  = json_decode(file_get_contents('players/money/'.$user_id));
        }else{



            $mon = array(
                "money" => 0

            );
            $usermon = $mon;
            js('players/money/'.$user_id,$mon);
        }
```

как исправить?